# Canvas Particle Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm new to canvas and particles but I'm having a play around with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/03ugq2de/).

There's a couple of things I'm trying to achieve here but I'm a bit stuck.

1. Make the text visible for longer before it breaks up into particles. As its not currently readable at the minute.
2. I'd also like to have it so that that theres a random particle movement which then forms into the text, stays in the text form for a few seconds and then breaks away into particles again. E.g. Random Particles > Particle formed text > Random Particles > Cleared screen.

As well as the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03ugq2de/) the code is below too:

```
/**
 * Init
 */
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas')[0];

window.onresize = function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

window.onresize();

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = 'bold 50px "Arial"';
ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';

var _particles = [];
var particlesLength = 0;

var currentText = "Create something beautiful";

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
}

/**
 * Create one particle
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
var createParticle = function createParticle(x, y) {
    _particles.push(new Particle(x, y));
};

/**
 * Check if pixel has alpha
 * @param pixels
 * @param i
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
var checkAlpha = function checkAlpha(pixels, i) {
    return pixels[i * 4 + 3] > 0;
};

/**
 * Create _particles
 */
var createParticles = function createParticles() {
    var textSize = ctx.measureText(currentText);
    ctx.fillText(
        currentText,
        Math.round((canvas.width / 2) - (textSize.width / 2)),
        Math.round(canvas.height / 2)
    );

    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(1, 1, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixels = imageData.data;
    var dataLength = imageData.width * imageData.height;

    //Loop through all pixels
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        var currentRow = Math.floor(i / imageData.width);
        var currentColumn = i - Math.floor(i / imageData.height);

        if (currentRow % 2 || currentColumn % 2) {
            continue;
        }

        //If alpha channel is greater than 0
        if (checkAlpha(pixels, i)) {
            var cy = ~~(i / imageData.width);
            var cx = ~~(i - (cy * imageData.width));

            createParticle(cx, cy);
        }
    }

    particlesLength = _particles.length;
};

/**
 * new Point(x, y)
 * @param x pointer
 * @param y pointer
 * @constructor
 */
var Point = function Point(x, y) {
    this.set(x, y);
};

Point.prototype = {
    set: function (x, y) {
        x = x || 0;
        y = y || x || 0;

        /**
         * x start pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         * @private
         */
        this._sX = x;

        /**
         * y start pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         * @private
         */
        this._sY = y;

        /**
         * Call reset
         */
        this.reset();
    },

    /**
     * add one point to another
     * @param point
     */
    add: function (point) {
        this.x += point.x;
        this.y += point.y;
    },

    /**
     * multiply two points
     * @param point
     */
    multiply: function (point) {
        this.x *= point.x;
        this.y *= point.y;
    },

    /**
     * Reset point
     */
    reset: function () {
        /**
         * x pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         */
        this.x = this._sX;

        /**
         * y pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         */
        this.y = this._sY;

        return this;
    },
};

var FRICT = new Point(0.98);
/**
 * Particle constructor
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @constructor
 */
var Particle = function Particle(x, y) {
    this.startPos = new Point(x, y);

    /**
     * Movement variables
     */
    this.v = new Point();
    this.a = new Point();

    /**
     * First init reset
     */
    this.reset();
};

Particle.prototype = {
    /**
     * Reset particle
     */
    reset: function () {
        this.x = this.startPos.x;
        this.y = this.startPos.y;

        this.life = Math.round(random() * 300);
        this.isActive = true;

        /**
         * Movement variables
         */
        this.v.reset();
        this.a.reset();
    },
    /**
     * Particle tick
     */
    tick: function () {
        if (!this.isActive) return;

        this.physics();
        this.checkLife();

        this.draw();

        return this.isActive;
    },
    /**
     * Calculate life
     */
    checkLife: function () {
        this.life -= 1;

        this.isActive = !(this.life < 1);
    },

    /**
     * Draw particle
     */
    draw: function () {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
    },

    /**
     * Calculate particle movement
     */
    physics: function () {
        this.a.x = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;
        this.a.y = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;

        this.v.add(this.a);
        this.v.multiply(FRICT);

        this.x += this.v.x;
        this.y += this.v.y;

        this.x = Math.round(this.x * 10) / 10;
        this.y = Math.round(this.y * 10) / 10;
    }
};

/**
 * Start the party
 */
createParticles();

/**
 * Clear canvas
 */
function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

(function clearLoop() {
    /**
     * Do clearing
     */
    clearCanvas();

    /**
     * next loop
     */
    requestAnimationFrame(clearLoop);
})();

/**
 * Main animation loop
 */
(function animLoop() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ea541b';
    var isAlive = true;

    /**
     * Loop _particles
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
        /**
         * If particle is active
         */
        if (_particles[i].tick()) isAlive = true;
    }



    /**
     * next loop
     */
    requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
})();

function resetParticles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
        _particles[i].reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just delay the physics for a few seconds so the user can see the text:**

```
// set a time that's 3 seconds in the future
var nextTime=performance.now()+3000;

// wait until the current time is >= nextTime
if(nextTime && performance.now()<nextTime){return;}else{nextTime=null;}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var random=Math.random;


/**
 * Init
 */
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

window.onresize = function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

window.onresize();

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = 'bold 50px "Arial"';
ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';

var _particles = [];
var particlesLength = 0;

var currentText = "Create something beautiful";

/**
 * Create one particle
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
var createParticle = function createParticle(x, y) {
    _particles.push(new Particle(x, y));
};

/**
 * Check if pixel has alpha
 * @param pixels
 * @param i
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
var checkAlpha = function checkAlpha(pixels, i) {
    return pixels[i * 4 + 3] > 0;
};

/**
 * Create _particles
 */
var createParticles = function createParticles() {
    var textSize = ctx.measureText(currentText);
    ctx.fillText(
        currentText,
        Math.round((canvas.width / 2) - (textSize.width / 2)),
        Math.round(canvas.height / 2)
    );

    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(1, 1, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixels = imageData.data;
    var dataLength = imageData.width * imageData.height;

    //Loop through all pixels
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        var currentRow = Math.floor(i / imageData.width);
        var currentColumn = i - Math.floor(i / imageData.height);

        if (currentRow % 2 || currentColumn % 2) {
            continue;
        }

        //If alpha channel is greater than 0
        if (checkAlpha(pixels, i)) {
            var cy = ~~(i / imageData.width);
            var cx = ~~(i - (cy * imageData.width));

            createParticle(cx, cy);
        }
    }

    particlesLength = _particles.length;
};

/**
 * new Point(x, y)
 * @param x pointer
 * @param y pointer
 * @constructor
 */
var Point = function Point(x, y) {
    this.set(x, y);
};

Point.prototype = {
    set: function (x, y) {
        x = x || 0;
        y = y || x || 0;

        /**
         * x start pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         * @private
         */
        this._sX = x;

        /**
         * y start pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         * @private
         */
        this._sY = y;

        /**
         * Call reset
         */
        this.reset();
    },

    /**
     * add one point to another
     * @param point
     */
    add: function (point) {
        this.x += point.x;
        this.y += point.y;
    },

    /**
     * multiply two points
     * @param point
     */
    multiply: function (point) {
        this.x *= point.x;
        this.y *= point.y;
    },

    /**
     * Reset point
     */
    reset: function () {
        /**
         * x pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         */
        this.x = this._sX;

        /**
         * y pointer
         * @type {*|number}
         */
        this.y = this._sY;

        return this;
    },
};

var FRICT = new Point(0.98);
/**
 * Particle constructor
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @constructor
 */
var Particle = function Particle(x, y) {
    this.startPos = new Point(x, y);

    /**
     * Movement variables
     */
    this.v = new Point();
    this.a = new Point();

    /**
     * First init reset
     */
    this.reset();
};

Particle.prototype = {
    /**
     * Reset particle
     */
    reset: function () {
        this.x = this.startPos.x;
        this.y = this.startPos.y;

        this.life = Math.round(random() * 300);
        this.isActive = true;

        /**
         * Movement variables
         */
        this.v.reset();
        this.a.reset();
    },
    /**
     * Particle tick
     */
    tick: function () {
        if (!this.isActive) return;

        this.physics();
        this.checkLife();

        this.draw();

        return this.isActive;
    },
    /**
     * Calculate life
     */
    checkLife: function () {
        this.life -= 1;

        this.isActive = !(this.life < 1);
    },

    /**
     * Draw particle
     */
    draw: function () {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
    },

    /**
     * Calculate particle movement
     */
    physics: function () {
        if(performance.now()<nextTime){return;}
        this.a.x = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;
        this.a.y = (random() - 0.5) * 0.8;

        this.v.add(this.a);
        this.v.multiply(FRICT);

        this.x += this.v.x;
        this.y += this.v.y;

        this.x = Math.round(this.x * 10) / 10;
        this.y = Math.round(this.y * 10) / 10;
    }
};

/**
 * Start the party
 */
var nextTime=performance.now()+3000;
createParticles();

/**
 * Clear canvas
 */
function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

(function clearLoop() {
    /**
     * Do clearing
     */
    clearCanvas();

    /**
     * next loop
     */
    requestAnimationFrame(clearLoop);
})();

/**
 * Main animation loop
 */
(function animLoop(time) {

    ctx.fillStyle = '#2c87c4';
    var isAlive = true;

    /**
     * Loop _particles
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
        /**
         * If particle is active
         */
        if (_particles[i].tick()) isAlive = true;
    }

   

    /**
     * next loop
     */
    requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
})();

function resetParticles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < particlesLength; i++) {
        _particles[i].reset();
    }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**I can think of at least 2 other ways to have variable speed animation.**

1. Use Robert Penner's [easing functions](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) to slow the beginning of your animation (to show the text longer) and speed up the ending of your animation (to show the dissolve faster). Here's a previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857717/grow-square-div-with-color-based-on-the-percentage-value-provided/29860759#29860759) with an example using easing in an animation.
2. `requestAnimationFrame` automatically sends in a timestamp argument that you can use to vary the execution of your animation. Use the timestamp to calculate elapsed time since the last animation loop. Allow a longer elapsed time at the beginning of your animation sequence. This allows the text to be displayed longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function that moves a point from a position to a desired location, with some randomness added to it. This is what I got:

```
function getRandomMove(pos,end,speed,randomness) {
    var a=Math.random()<randomness
        ? Math.random()*Math.PI/2
        : Math.atan2(end.y-pos.y,end.x-pos.x);
    dist=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(end.x-pos.x,2)+Math.pow(end.y-pos.y,2));
    var spd=Math.min(speed,dist);
    return { x: pos.x+spd*Math.cos(a), y: pos.y+spd*Math.sin(a), dist:dist-spd };
}
```

Where speed is the speed you want the particle to move and randomness is something between 0 and 0.5 exclusively (more is possible, but then you just get a very slow or even memory breaking execution). You can set randomness to a small value, because it will adapt to the ticks anyway if it is too small.

The problem with this is that if you use it with every particle, you will probably not get all particles where you want them all at the same time. That is why I thought of this function to generate the entire path from one location to another in a specified number of steps:

```
function reduceMoves(moves,ticks) {
    var temp=[];
    for (var i=0; i<moves.length-2; i++) {
        var m1=moves[i];
        var m2=moves[i+2];
        temp.push({index:i+1,dist:Math.sqrt(Math.pow(m1.x-m2.x,2)+Math.pow(m1.y-m2.y,2))});
    }
    temp.sort(function(a,b) { return a.dist-b.dist; });
    temp=temp.splice(0,moves.length-ticks);
    temp.sort(function(a,b) { return b.index-a.index });
    temp.forEach(function(t) {
        moves.splice(t.index,1);
    });
}

function moveRandomly(pos,end,speed,randomness,ticks) {
    var move=pos;
    var result=[move];
    var dist=100000;
    while (dist>0.1) {
        move=getRandomMove(move,end,speed,randomness);
        result.push(move);
        dist=move.dist;
    }
    move.x=end.x;
    move.y=end.y;
    if (result.length<ticks) {
        return moveRandomly(pos,end,speed,randomness+0.1,ticks);
    }
    reduceMoves(result,ticks);
    return result;
}
```

Use it as

```
var pos={x:Math.random()*500,y:Math.random()*500};
var end={x:Math.random()*500,y:Math.random()*500};
var moves=moveRandomly(pos,end,1,0.2,100);
```

I haven't had time to test it and I don't know if it is what you're looking for, but I hope so.