# Get started with animated typography/particles in javascript (mapping particles to a word)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, particles, particle-system

Alright, so I have a good deal of experience with HTML and CSS, and some experience with Javascript (I can write basic functions and have coded in similar languages).

I'm looking to start some visual projects and am specifically interested in getting into particle systems. I have an idea for something similar to Codecademy's name generator here (https://www.codecademy.com/courses/animate-your-name/0/1) where particles are mapped to a word and move if hovered over. It seems as though alphabet.js is what's really behind Codecademy's demo however I can't understand exactly how they mapped the particles to a word, etc.

I've done some basic tutorials just creating rudimentary particles in a canvas but I'm not sure a canvas is the best way to go - demos that utilize one of the many libraries available (such as http://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/examples/particles.html) don't use a canvas.

So my question is - what is the best way for a beginner/intermediate in Javascript to start with particle systems? Specifically to accomplish the Codecademy name effect or similar? Should I try to use canvas or which library would be best to start with and how would you recommend starting?

Comment: [**you may think this link interesting**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/03/interactive-particles-slideshow/)

Answer (score 0):

The code for this project is achievable for your intermediate JS programmer status.

**How the CodeAcademy project works ...**

- Start by building each letter out of circles and saving each circle's centerpoint in an array. The alphabet.js script holds that array of circle centerpoints.
- On `mousemove` events, test which circles are within a specified radius of the mouse position. Then animate each of those discovered circles radially outward from the mouse position using simple trigonometry.
- When the mouse moves again, test which circles are no longer within the specified radius of the current mouse position. Then animate each of those "outside" circles back towards their original positions.

You can also use native html5 canvas without any libraries...

**Another approach allowing any text to be "dissolved" and reassembled**

- Start by drawing the text on the canvas. BTW, this approach will "dissolve" any drawing, not just text.
- Use `context.getImageData` to fetch the opacity value of every pixel on the canvas. Determine which pixels on the canvas contain parts of the text. You can tell if a pixel is part of the text because it will be opaque rather than transparent.

Now do the same procedure that CodeAcademy did with their circles -- but use your pixels:

- On `mousemove` events, test which pixels are within a specified radius of the mouse position. Then animate each of those discovered pixels radially outward from the mouse position using simple trigonometry.
- When the mouse moves again, test which pixels are no longer within the specified radius of the current mouse position. Then animate each of those "outside" pixels back towards their original positions.

**[Addition: mousemove event to test if circles are within mouse distance]**

*Note:* You probably want to keep an animation frame running that moves circles closer or further from their original positions based on a flag (isInside) for each circle.

```
function handleMouseMove(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calc the current mouse position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // test each circle to see if it's inside or outside
    // radius of 40px to current mouse position
    // circles[] is an array of circle objects shaped like this
    //      {x:,y:,r:,originalX:,originalY:,isInside:}
    var radius=40;
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var c=circles[i];
        var dx=c.x-mouseX;
        var dy=c.y-mouseY;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<radius*radius){
            c.isInside=true;
            // move c.x & c.y away from its originalX & originalY
        }else{
            c.isInside=false;
            // if the circle is not already back at it's originalX, originalY
            // then move c.x & c.y back towards its originalX, originalY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide some example code for the first basic steps? I'd like to dissolve the text - could you provide an example of mousmove used to test which pixels are within a specified radius of the mouse position? I'm new to this

Comment: I've added a skeleton example `mousemove` code. That should get you started ... the rest is for your learning experience. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, that helps, but i'm still unclear as to how to use context.getImageData as I've never used this before.. is there any way you would provide a basic example of modifying the pixels that make up a line of text as well? Just trying to grasp this here

Comment: Time does not permit more examples, but perhaps you can look at this previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156150/canvas-particle-text/36161809#36161809) as an example.