# Which kinds of web technologies can be used to create dynamic animations? In particular how were these effects created?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I found this [website](http://www.webable.digital) home-page effect very cool. How can one create these kinds of animation effects ? Do these kinds of effects require additional plugins?

Thank You

Comment: Here you have the .js file : http://www.webable.digital/js/function.js . It's a bit complex... a great work for sure. (3k lines of code)

Comment: Start with this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369819/get-started-with-animated-typography-particles-in-javascript-mapping-particles/36376811#36376811) that shows how to push particles outward from the mouse and reassemble those particles when the mouse move on.

Comment: Its worth pointing out that's a commercial plugin called ParticleSlider

Answer (score 5):

here is a code pen http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/vKmJbA

here is the code they are using

```
//--star animation

var canvas = document.getElementById("maincanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var stars = [];
var colours = ["white"];

canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

var centre = new Vector2(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

//In terms of canvas width to look consistent on different resolutions
var spawnWidth = canvas.width / 2;
var spawnHeight = canvas.height / 2;

//Star properties
var maxStars = 50;
var spawnRadius = 0.1;
var sizeIncreaseFactor = 0.004;

function loop() {
    clear();
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        stars[i].update();
    }
}

function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        stars[i].draw();
    }
}

function populateStarField() {
    for (var i = 0; i < maxStars; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        stars.push(new star(new Vector2(x, y), getVelocity(new Vector2(x, y), centre), new Vector2(), spawnRadius, getRandomColour()));
    }
}

function getRandomColour() {
    return colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
}

function addStar() {
    var x = centre.x + Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnWidth) - (spawnWidth / 2);
    var y = centre.y + Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnHeight) - (spawnHeight / 2);
    var velocity = getVelocity(new Vector2(x, y), centre);
    stars.push(new star(new Vector2(x, y), velocity, new Vector2((velocity.x / 30), (velocity.y / 30)), spawnRadius, getRandomColour()));
}

function getVelocity(location, centre) {
    var velocity = new Vector2();

    var distance = getDistanceBetween(location, centre, true);
    var scaledXDist = distance.x / (centre.x);
    var scaledYDist = distance.y / (centre.y);

    velocity.x = scaledXDist * 8;
    velocity.y = scaledYDist * 6;

    if (location.x < centre.x) {
        velocity.x = -velocity.x;
    }
    if (location.y < centre.y) {
        velocity.y = -velocity.y;
    }
    return velocity;
}

function getDistanceBetween(vector1, vector2, vectorOut) {
    var dx = Math.abs(vector1.x - vector2.x);
    var dy = Math.abs(vector1.y - vector2.y);
    if (!vectorOut) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
    } else {
        return new Vector2(dx, dy);
    }
}

function star(location, velocity, acceleration, radius, colour) {
    this.location = location || new Vector2();
    this.velocity = velocity || new Vector2();
    this.acceleration = acceleration || new Vector2();
    this.radius = radius || 1;
    this.startRadius = radius;
    this.colour = colour || "#EEE";
}
star.prototype.move = function() {
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.location.add(this.velocity);
}
star.prototype.update = function() {
    this.move();

    //Increase size to give appearance of moving closer
    this.radius = this.startRadius + (getDistanceBetween(this.location, centre, false) * sizeIncreaseFactor);

    //Remove if out of bounds, replace with new
    if (this.location.x < 0 ||
        this.location.x > canvas.width ||
        this.location.y < 0 ||
        this.location.y > canvas.height) {
        var index = stars.indexOf(this);
        if (index > -1) {
            stars.splice(index, 1);
            addStar();
        }
    }
}
star.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
    ctx.arc(this.location.x, this.location.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}

function Vector2(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}
Vector2.prototype.add = function(vector) {
    this.x += vector.x;
    this.y += vector.y;
}
Vector2.prototype.subtract = function(vector) {
    this.x -= vector.x;
    this.y -= vector.y;
}
populateStarField();
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: Good start with the outbound stars. Further in the animation the particles re-assemble into the company logo.

Comment: http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/vKmJbA  here is a codepen

Answer (score 3):

This effect makes use of html5 Canvas which provides an array of pixels which can be manipulated by code.

In particular they are using the Commercial Particle Slider plugin for the image decomposition: http://particleslider.com/ along with custom code for the star-field, as you can see in the previous answer.

In this specific example, this is actually a poor example of usability -- especially for a home page -- since some users might have slower computers and there is no optimization built in (from what I could observe).

It is though an admittedly cool plugin.

Learn more about html5 canvas here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp